# Method Illuminate\View\View::header does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to produce a js file to let other webmasters use my news headlines in their websites:

```
Route::get('/script/news/{slug}/{count}.js',function($slug,$count) {
      return view('webmaster_script')->
      with(compact("slug","count"))->
      header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
});
```

But it says

> BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\View\View::header does not
> exist

How can I fix it?

Script content is generated successfully . I just want to change the MIME type.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#view-responses) gives following example

> If you need control over the response's status and headers but also need to return a view as the response's content, you should use the view method:
>
> ```
> return response()
>            ->view('hello', $data, 200)
>            ->header('Content-Type', $type);
> ```

So following should work:

```
 return response()
    ->view('webmaster_script', compact("slug", "count"))
    ->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
```